# Different slide intervals for Views Slideshow

Tags: javascript, views

I've created a slideshow using [Views Slideshow](http://drupal.org/project/views_slideshow) and the [Cycle plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/). In the Slideshow settings, there are advanced transition options that allow you to set the timer delay between slides. The project I'm working on requires that the delay between slides be different for each slide, so I need a way to do something like this:

- Slide 1: 3000 ms
- Slide 2: 5000 ms
- Slide 3: 10000 ms

I have searched and cannot find a way to accomplish this easily. Is there something I'm missing, or would this require a custom module?

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to override the defaults with something like this:

```
$('.views-slideshow-cycle-main-frame').each(function(index) {
  var timer = 3000;
  if (index == 1) timer = 5000;
  if (index == 2) timer = 10000;
  $(this).cycle({
    timeout : timer
  });
});
```

This goes in an external js file or using [drupal_add_js()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_add_js/7).